# can't pass local variable into button decorator

Tags: python, class, discord.py, decorator

How do I pass the `self.canCraft` variable into the decorator? I understand the problem why it doesn't work, but I cant find a solution. I dont want to do it with a global variable.

```
class CraftView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, viewOwner, craftItem, canCraft):
        super().__init__()
        self.viewOwner = viewOwner
        self.craftItem = craftItem
        self.canCraft = canCraft

    @discord.ui.button(label="Craft", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="", disabled=self.canCraft)
    async def button_callback(self, interaction: Interaction, button: ui.Button):
        pass
```

Comment: Show the code (at least additionally) as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off subclassing [discord.ui.Button](https://(https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20button#discord.ui.Button)) and adding it to a view like so-

```py
import discord

class CraftButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, label:str, emoji:str, disabled:bool, style:discord.ButtonStyle=discord.ButtonStyle.primary):
        super().__init__(label=label, emoji=emoji, disabled=disabled, style=style)

    async def callback(interaction:discord.Interaction):
        ...

class CraftView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, view_owner, craft_item, can_craft):
        super().__init__()
        self.view_owner = view_owner
        self.craft_item = craft_item
        self.add_item(CraftButton("Craft", "", can_craft))
```